# How to get the modified date of an .xls file using xlrd

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

Let me try to improve this question, as it is still valid for me.

I have been using Openpyxl to read Excel files for a while. Now I need to extend the capability of my script to handle "legacy" Excel files that are not supported by Openpyxl. For this I use xlrd and xlutils.

On issue I have yet to solve is how to get the modified date of an .xls file in the case where I don't have the path. Using Openpyxl, I can get this as Workbook.properties.modified, as a datetime object. With xlrd I am struggling. A workaround would be to figure out the path to the file (which may be input to my function as a file like object) and to use `os.path.getmtime`, but I am not sure if that is equivalent.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't think `os.path.getmtime` gives you the same thing as `Workbook.properties.modified`. You can test this for yourself simply by examining some Excel files using both methods. To create greater separation between the date in the file system and the date in the workbook, save a workbook without changing its contents. Unfortunately, xlrd is not likely to gain any new capabilities, especially when it comes to the older .xls files. So unless you are prepared to research the guts of the BIFF format yourself, the file system date is your best bet. It's probably better than nothing.

Comment: I would settle for the file system date, but don't know how to get it for a file object. Is it possible?

Comment: By "file system date" I just meant your own proposal to use `os.path.getmtime`. But now I am realizing what you mean is that you might not know the path to any actual file system file, so then the problem becomes how to get that path. If your function truly accepts arbitrary "file objects", then it's possible there's no path at all (the bytes may only exist in memory and not anywhere in the file system). In that case, maybe you have no choice but to just use the system time at the moment you receive the data.

Comment: @JohnY :That's what I'm doing now! :) Based on your last remark I feel better about it!

Answer (score 2):

I just came across your post while searching for a solution myself. Seems like

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename=fn)
wb.props.get('modified')
```

does the job.

xlrd==1.2.0

Comment: Thank you for contributing! Did you verify this for a .xls file, or only for a .xlsx file? I am not able to successfully use this solution in the first case.

Comment: I had tested with .xlsx. Now I just tried with an .xls file, and wb.props is not there. Sorry :-(

Comment: No worries. Better luck next time!